# Previous passwords with password_hash

Tags: php

I have a policy requirement to make sure new passwords are not repetitions of the previous 5 passwords.
using the PHP [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function i get a randomly salted password.  The problem is if is store the hash the same password always has a different hash (as expected).

If I have a per-user salt (randomly making it on user row creation) i will get a php warning for using a deprecated salt.
Is there a better way of implementing this or should I just fall back and use [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)?

Comment: Heh. Going to less secure methods, to enforce a silly company policy.

Comment: Just store the previous 5 password hashes (together with their salts) and when they change their password use `password_verify` five times to check if it matches any of the previous five passwords.

Comment: @paulpro - does the password_hash function return the complete salt?

Comment: Yes, it returns the salt and the resulting hash together in one string.